# Why does right inverse implies surjection

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Basically, as it says in the title I require an answer on why is it so that if a function has a right inverse then it is surjective.
I am currently self studying abstract algebra and please take that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism in a category whose objects are sets with additional structure (e.g. groups, rings, etc), and $g:Y\to X$ satisfies $f\circ g=1_Y,$ then by a pure set theoretical argument $f$ is surjective: If $y\in Y$ let $x=g(y)\in X,$ then $f(x)=f\circ g(y)=y.$

Answer (score 0):

The right inverse of $f:A\to B$ is the function $h:B\to A$ such that $(f\circ h)(x)=x\ \forall x\in B$.

The identity function is surjective on $B$ which means $f\circ h$ is surjective on $B$. This means that $f$ has to be surjective, because the range of $f\circ h$ is a subset of the range of $f$;

$\ R(f\circ h)\subseteq R(f)\subseteq B$

$R(f\circ h)=B\implies R(f)=B$

Answer (score 0):

If $f:A\to B$ has a right inverse, $\exists g:B\to A:f\circ g=id_B$.  Since $f\circ g$ is onto, $f$ must be onto.